# Returned error: unknown account when sending with web3-react and Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

i'm getting this unknow account error while trying to send some tokens to a staking contract. Does someone experienced this or have any solution?

My function the the frontend:

```
const { account } = useWeb3React()

  const setStake = async () => {
    try{  

     
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'))
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const deployedNetwork = StakeBSCM.networks[networkId];
    const stakebscm = new web3.eth.Contract(StakeBSCM.abi, deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,)
    const addresses = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); 
    console.log(addresses[0])  
    await stakebscm.methods.stake(output).send({from: account})
    .then(function(receipt){console.log(receipt)})

    

  } catch (err){

    console.log(err)

  }
}
```

My function on the contract

```
    function stake(uint256 amount) public {
        require(amount > 0, "Stake amount must be > 0");
        uint256 stakerBSCMBalance = BSCMemepadContract.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        require(stakerBSCMBalance >= amount, "Caller balance < amount");
        Staker memory _staker = stakerInfo[msg.sender];
        if (!_staker.isPresent) {
            _staker.isPresent = true;
            stakers.push(msg.sender);
            //solhint-disable-next-line not-rely-on-time
            _staker.stakedAt = block.timestamp;
        }

        // It implies a staker has already staked then unstaked and now again is staking
        if (_staker.isPresent && (_staker.stakedAt == 0) && (_staker.amount == 0)) {
            //solhint-disable-next-line not-rely-on-time
            _staker.stakedAt = block.timestamp;
        }

        BSCMemepadContract.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        totalBSCMemepadStaked += amount;
        _staker.amount += amount;
        stakerInfo[msg.sender] = _staker; // Write Staker info to contract storage
        emit Stake(msg.sender, amount, _staker.stakedAt);
    }
```

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@web3-react/abstract-connector": "^6.0.7",
    "@web3-react/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
    "@web3-react/types": "^6.0.7",
    "ethers": "^5.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.26",
    "web3-eth": "1.0.0-beta.26",
    "web3-eth-contract": "1.0.0-beta.26"
  },
```

Comment: is the `useWeb3React` hook custom made ? If so could you please show its content ? The web3-react documentation `https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-react` uses :  `const context = useWeb3Context()` You should find the account in `context.account`.

Comment: This code works, for example:

```
const { active, account } = useWeb3React()

  
          const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'))
          const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
          const deployedNetwork = BSCMemepad.networks[networkId];
          const bscmemepad = new web3.eth.Contract(BSCMemepad.abi, deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,)
          await bscmemepad.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
          .then(response => setMemepadBalance(response))
          .then(console.log(memepadBalance))

Comment: Ah yes it's deeper in the doc : https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/tree/d0b038c748a42ec85641a307e6c588546d86afc2/docs#useweb3react my bad. You do have the same provider structure for both of those codes right ?

Comment: Basically. The difference is that one is a call() and the other is a send()